# Length in Jsoup Element.select regex

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

is the length part of the regex in Jsoup's `Element.select` supposed to work? I am trying to find paragraph elements with content that is between 3 and 30 characters long, but it doesn't seem to work. I am doing it like this:

```
Elements e = doc.select("p:matchesOwn({3,30}");
```

It seems to return all p elements, no matter how long they are.

What am I not getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex works for me:

```
String html = "<p>aaa</p>" +
        "<p>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>" +
        "<p>cccc</p>" +
        "<p>d</p>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements e = doc.select("p:matches(^.{3,30}$)");

System.out.println(e);
```

Which outputs:

```
<p>aaa</p>
<p>cccc</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what your looking for but i have found that when working with Jsoup it "selects" all elements. instead try and do it as a two step thing

1. Select all elements
2. loop through them and find the ones that has a length between 3 and 30

like such:

```
Elements e = doc.select("p")
for (Elements paragrah: e) {
    if(paragrah.toString().length() > 3 && paragrah.toString().length <= 30){

    }
}
```